# Image display codeigniter fails 

Tags: image, codeigniter, hyperlink

I can upload image to the directory but can not disply it on the page.
Tried using static html code and codeigniter `img()` function, both are not working.

Here is my code:

```
<image src="./applications/views/uploads/image.jpeg" />
```

and

```
$this->output->set_header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$data['image'] = $this->load->file('../uploads/taurus.jpeg');
```

the first code shows me broken image the second one shows Unable to load the requested file: `taurus.jpeg`

Comment: and the image is in ...?

Answer (score 0):

```
<image src="./applications/views/uploads/image.jpeg" />
```

By default, CodeIgniter denies access to the application folder which is why I suspect this isn't working.

```
$this->output->set_header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$data['image'] = $this->load->file('../uploads/taurus.jpeg');
```

I suspect this isn't working because your path is incorrect.  The path is relative to the `index.php` file in the root of your application, not the file this code is in.  Secondly, `$this->load->file()` sends to file contents to the browser so this wouldn't work anyway.

A solution would be to move your `uploads` folder to a web accessible location.  For example, place the `uploads` folder into the root of your application - the same folder as your `index.php` file.  Then you can display your image like this:

```
<image src="/uploads/image.jpeg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the dot (.) in the URL so your src url reads: "/applications/views/uploads/image.jpeg"